# How to set number of troops in Empire total war

Tags: empire-total-war

I was playing Empire Total War and I guess I have done something because I was going to train up some line Infantry and it said 160 men which was odd because in all of my previous games I only had 120 men. Later I was going to do a battle and it also had 160 men in my Infantry. I was going to reload one of my older Prussian games it I only had 120 men in my Line infantry. I don't like having more troops than I need because in the early game I cant fire by rank so I need to extend my lines so I have as many men firing at any given moment. So how do I change the number of troops?

Answer (score 1):

In any Total War game you can't really control the number of troops in a unit (except by getting them killed) - whenever a unit is created it will have always the maximum available number of soldiers for this type. However, the units differ between different countries, which also includes the maximum number of soldiers.

In wiki you can read that:

> Every major faction in the game has slightly different line infantry. The British, for example, have some of the finest all-round line infantry in the game, while Russian line infantry have very poor shooting characteristics but have unparalleled charging bonuses. The Ottoman equivalents of line infantry are the Isarelys and the Nizam-I Cedit infantry, while the Maratha Confederacy have Bargir Infantry and Sikh Musketeers.
>
> **Austrians have the advantage of having line infantry regiments with 25% more manpower. For example, on ultra settings a full non-Austrian regiment has 160 men**; Austrian regiments have 200, instead. On the other hand, Austrian line infantry have generally very poor stats and are the most expensive to field.

Saying that, you can also apparently control the number of [soldiers in an unit in the game settings](https://forums.totalwar.com/discussion/7156/how-to-set-the-number-of-soldiers-in-a-unit-size) in the graphic options

[image]

Comment: It's not purely cosmetic and performance reason. In general Total War games are balanced around large and ultra unit scale and the balance can get pretty iffy with smaller unit scales. The main issue is that smaller regiments break easier and the damage dealt by a cavalry charge or artillery fire isn't too different compared to larger unit scales. It's most egregious in Warhammer with its single entity units, but the effect can also be seen in the other games.

Comment: This is **not a purely cosmetic setting**! It is also **not just a performance setting**! Altering it does effect the performance of your machine in battles with maxed/multiple army battles, but it does also effect unit cohesion as @Dulkan mentioned. It applies to a save game and that is why the OP is seeing different results for different save games (with the same faction) - they must have set a larger unit size in the current game they are playing, and a smaller size in the previous one.

Comment: Weather its for cosmetic or performance or not it still did solve my problem

Comment: @MilesMeans Are you playing the same faction in both games?

Comment: No I play the Prussians, Indians, and the Swedish most the time.

Comment: @MilesMeans Hmm, if you don't play Austria then (who has more units in Line Infantry), try reducing the unit size in the graphic settings. Interensting discussion here: http://etw.heavengames.com/cgi-bin/forums/display.cgi?action=ct&f=10,8365,100,all